# Is an inclusion morphism flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, flatness

I find it really hard to understand the definition of *flat*. There are so many details, but I didn't find any "intuitive" geometric or algebraic approach to this type of functions.

To my problem: I have the simple inclusion morphism $i:T\simeq(\mathbb{C}^*)^n \to X_\Sigma$ between a torus $T$ and a $n$-dimensional toric variety $X_\Sigma$. Is it in general true that this morphism is flat? If not, does this hold for specific toric varieties (maybe only complete, smooth, simplicial or projective ones)?

I have no idea how to approach this question as the definition of flat requires looking at the stalks,... However, this seems a bit overkill and I think there should be a simple answer to such a "simple" morphism. Any suggestions?

Comment: The inclusion of an open subvariety (or subscheme, if you like) is flat.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have some literature where I can find out more about flatness?

Comment: Not really, but I'm not an expert. I have the impression flatness is rather mysterious. However, the situation here is much simpler because the inclusion of an open subvariety is an isomorphism on all stalks of the structure sheaves.

Comment: Ah, this really makes it easier, I didn't see that point. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An immersion of (locally Noetherian) schemes is flat if and only if it is an open immersion, or a closed immersion of connected components.

Open immersions are flat since the induced maps on stalks are isomorphisms, as pointed out by Zhen Lin in the comments.

Suppose $\phi\colon Z\to X$ is a closed immersion and assume it is flat. The question is local so we may assume that $X=\text{Spec}(R)$, $Z=\text{Spec}(R/I)$, and $\phi$ is induced by the quotient map $R\to R/I$. Consider the SES
$$0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0.$$
By assumption $R/I$ is a flat $R$-module, so we get an exact sequence
$$0\to I/I^2\to R/I\to R/I\to 0$$
after tensoring with $R/I$. The last map is an isomorphism so $I^2=I$. Since $X$ is locally noetherian $I$ is finitely generated and Nakayama's lemma implies that $I=(e)$ where $e^2=e$. This means that $R\simeq R/(1-e)\times R/(e)$ and hence $Z$ is a union of connected components of $X$.

Note: You can remove the Noetherian hypothesis and only assume that $I$ is finitely generated. I'm not sure if the same holds when $I$ is infinitely generated, or if there are pathological examples.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Two questions: How exactly did the tensoring with $R/I$ worked? Isn't $R/I\otimes_R R/I = (R/I)^2$ and how do you get $I/I^2$?

Comment: For any $R$-module $M$ one has the identity $R/I \otimes_R M\simeq M/IM$. Take $I=M$ and you'll get $R/I\otimes_R I\simeq I/I^2$. Similarly, taking $M=R/I$ gives you the identity $R/I\otimes_R R/I\simeq R/I$.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the clarification